# Using Caffeinate command in MacOS

Tags: macos, process, terminal, thread-sleep

I'm running a torch implementation of DCgan. As the training is taking a lot of time, I thought of using caffeinate in Macos in order to keep the system awake until the training and generating finishes. So, I used the `ps` command and found the following as output.

```
PID TTY           TIME CMD
 5607 ttys000    0:00.18 -bash
 6206 ttys000   16:06.47 python dcgan_nocomment.py
 6209 ttys000    0:01.49 python dcgan_nocomment.py
 6210 ttys000    0:01.53 python dcgan_nocomment.py
 6318 ttys001    0:00.03 -bash
```

In order to use caffeinate, which process pid should I need to consider to put in the following command

`caffeinate -disu -w [pid]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also use `caffeinate` in utility mode, where you don't need to provide a pid, but a utility that should be executed. E.g. wrap your work in a shell script `mywork.sh` and:

```
caffeinate -disu mywork.sh
```